# How can apply superadmin permissions to handle enable/disable events for GPS in Android App

Tags: android, gps, application-settings, administrator

I have been trying to build an android app that will not allow device user to change/edit GPS settings from anywhere on device while user is driving at speed say more than 20MPH.

Once user crosses 20MPH, user will not be able to disable GPS setting from notification bar or from internal settings.

How can apply this using system superadmin/administrator permissions to handle enable/disable events for GPS in Android App? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use these permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Register one listener for GPS enable or disable .

```
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Switch on GPS." + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and add this to listen for change in GPS status

```
locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener)
```

As and when GPS is disabled by USER , you will enable it by code . Code to enable GPS is

```
        Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,true);
```

Use proper permissions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enabling/disabling GPS is asynchronous process by design. You can listen for the attempt to disable and reenable GPS back. But you cannot prevent the actual disabling. 
   The GPS will be off for a second or few.

Or you have to design your own ROM implementing some kind of lock for GPS available only to your own applications.

1. To obtain the SuperAdmin privileges your need a) root and b) to design a small stub application installed in /system/app directory.

As a sample of all above you may take my GPSToggler from https://github.com/sms2000/GPSToggler.
It works more or less and can be adopted for your needs.