# How to turn GPS on and off?

Tags: android, gps, location

Does Android allow GPS to be turned on and off programmatically?

I am using the code [functions turnGPSon() & turnGPSoff()] below ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262946/how-to-enable-gps-in-android))

I am using using the function "GPSStatus()" to detect if GPS is on or not.

Two problems:

1. turnGPSoff() is NOT working. 
   turnGPSon() is able to turn the GPS on ('I think' because I can see the GPS symbol in the top left status icon, but GPS button in control center [galaxy s3] is not highlighted though, and I am getting accurate loation)
2. GPSStatus() is ALWAYS returning false - am I checking the correct way?

My goal is only to turn GPS on and off pro grammatically? (Is it true that Android does not allow GPS to be turned on and off programmatically? as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431598/turn-on-off-gps-android))

```
    private boolean GPSStatus() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver,    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    return gpsStatus;
    }


    public void turnGPSOn()
    {        
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}



// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff()
{

    myLogger.displayMsgs("in turnGPSoff()", true, true);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate, original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738883/how-can-apply-superadmin-permissions-to-handle-enable-disable-events-for-gps-in)

Answer:

(You would need rootaccess for full control so it's pretty much not possible)

Original answer:

1. Enabling/disabling GPS is asynchronous process by design. You can listen for the attempt to disable and reenable GPS back. But you cannot prevent the actual disabling. The GPS will be off for a second or few.
   Or you have to design your own ROM implementing some kind of lock for GPS available only to your own applications.

To obtain the SuperAdmin privileges your need a) root and b) to design a small stub application installed in /system/app directory.
As a sample of all above you may take my GPSToggler from https://github.com/sms2000/GPSToggler. It works more or less and can be adopted for your needs.